# Telegram inline keyboard and input data by user

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, google-apps-script, telegram-bot

I'm developing a Telegram bot on Google Apps Script for personal purposes: entering expenses / incomes for different types.

I have several types of expenses that I record in Google Spreadsheets.

### My idea

[image]

I got a problem implementing the expense input.
I liked how this is implemented in the official bot @BotFather

### @BotFather

[image]

How can you implement this correctly? Preferably with GAS.

Thanks.

**Bot.gs**

```
var token = "<BOT_TOKEN>";
var telegramUrl = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token;
var webAppUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/<ID>/exec";

function getMe() {
  var url = telegramUrl + "/getMe";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function setWebhook() {
  var url = telegramUrl + "/setWebhook?url=" + webAppUrl;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function deletWebhook() {
  var url = telegramUrl + "/setWebhook";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
}

function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Webhook is working.");
}

// Send message
function sendMessage(chat_id, text) {
  var data = {
    method: "post",
    payload: {
      method: "sendMessage",
      chat_id: String(chat_id),
      text: text,
      parse_mode: "HTML",
      disable_web_page_preview: true
    }
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token + "/", data);
}

// Delete message
function deleteMessage(chat_id, message_id) {
  var data = {
    method: "post",
    payload: {
      method: "deleteMessage",
      chat_id: String(chat_id),
      message_id: parseInt(message_id, 10)
    }
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token + "/", data);
}

// Edit message
function editMessage(chat_id, message_id, text) {
  var data = {
    method: "post",
    payload: {
      method: "editMessageText",
      chat_id: String(chat_id),
      message_id: parseInt(message_id, 10),
      text: text,
      parse_mode: "HTML",
      disable_web_page_preview: true
    }
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token + "/", data);
}

// Send message and keyboard
function sendMessageKeyboard(chat_id, text, keyboard) {
  var data = {
    method: "post",
    payload: {
      method: "sendMessage",
      chat_id: String(chat_id),
      text: text,
      parse_mode: "HTML",
      reply_markup: JSON.stringify(keyboard)
    }
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token + "/", data);
}

// Hide keyboard
function hideKeyBoard(chat_id, message_id) {
  var data = {
    method: "post",
    payload: {
      method: "editMessageReplyMarkup",
      chat_id: String(chat_id),
      message_id: parseInt(message_id, 10)
    }
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token + "/", data);
}

// Replace keyboard
function replaceKeyBoard(chat_id, message_id,keyboard) {
  var data = {
    method: "post",
    payload: {
      method: "editMessageReplyMarkup",
      chat_id: String(chat_id),
      message_id: parseInt(message_id, 10),
      reply_markup: JSON.stringify(keyboard)
    }
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token + "/", data);
}
```

**doPost.gs**

```
function doPost(e) {
  var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);

  if (contents.callback_query) {

    var message_id = contents.callback_query.message.message_id;
    var data = contents.callback_query.data;
    var multiData = data.split(" ");
    var chat_id = contents.callback_query.from.id;

    if (data == 'Back') {
      replaceKeyBoard(chat_id, message_id, KEYBOARD_COMPANIES);

    } else if (data == 'Cancel') {
      deleteMessage(chat_id, message_id);
      sendMessageKeyboard(chat_id, "Choose the action:", KEYBOARD_COMPANIES);

    } else if (data == 'Common') {
      replaceKeyBoard(chat_id, message_id, KEYBOARD_COMMON);

    } else if ((multiData[1]) && (multiData[0] == 'Common')) {
      deleteMessage(chat_id, message_id);
      sendMessageKeyboard(chat_id, "<b>Expense: " + multiData[0] + " -> " + multiData[1] + ".</b> Input the value:", KEYBOARD_INPUT);
    }

} else if (contents.message) {

    var chat_id = contents.message.from.id;
    var text = contents.message.text;

    if (text == "/start") {
      deleteMessage(chat_id, contents.message.message_id)
      sendMessageKeyboard(chat_id, "Choose the action:", KEYBOARD_COMPANIES);

    } else if (!isNaN(parseFloat(text)) && isFinite(text)) {
      for (var i = 0; i < logins.length; i++) {
        if (chat_id == logins[i]) {
          sBot.getRange("C" + (i + 2)).setValue(text);
          replaceKeyBoard(chat_id, sBot.getRange("D" + (i + 2)).getValue());
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Keyboard.gs**

```
// 1 Companies
var KEYBOARD_COMPANIES = {
  "inline_keyboard": [
    [{ "text": "Common", 'callback_data': 'Common' }],
    [{ "text": "Smoky Unicorn", 'callback_data': 'Smoky Unicorn' }],
    [{ "text": "Pussy Stuff", 'callback_data': 'Pussy Stuff' }],
    [{ "text": "Trash Seller", 'callback_data': 'Trash Seller' }]
  ]
};

// 1.1 Common
var KEYBOARD_COMMON = {
  "inline_keyboard": [
    [{ "text": "Back", 'callback_data': 'Back' }],
    [{ "text": "Taxi", 'callback_data': 'Common Taxi' }],
    [{ "text": "Food", 'callback_data': 'Common Food' }],
    [{ "text": "Party", 'callback_data': 'Common Party' }]
  ]
};

// Reply
var FORCE_REPLY = {
  "force_reply": true
};

// Input the value
var KEYBOARD_INPUT = {
  "inline_keyboard": [
    [{ "text": "Cancel", 'callback_data': 'Cancel' }]
  ]
};
```

**Functions.gs**

```
// Global
var todayMonth = getMonthToday();
var NEWL = String.fromCharCode(10); // newline

var accId = "<Spreadsheet_ID"; // Accounting Spreadsheet
var acc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(accId);
var sAcc = acc.getSheetByName(todayMonth);
var sBot = acc.getSheetByName("Bot");

// @usernames who have access to the bot
var andreyChatId = sBot.getRange("B2").getValue();
var donyChatId = sBot.getRange("B3").getValue();

// chat_id who have access to the bot
var logins = ["99587408", "155390785"];

// Get current month
function getMonthToday() {
  var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  var todayDate = new Date();
  var todayMonth = months[todayDate.getMonth()];

  return todayMonth;
}
```

Comment: In order to better assist you it'd be helpful to the community if you show what have you tried so far, a small piece of code or what's your current issue so we can better help you. Keep in mind that Stack Overflow is made for solving issues mostly and other community members can see it in order to solve their own issues related to a specific project. For that reason there should be a problem that you tried to solve but you got stuck, as I mentioned before can you please provide more info?